# Is there a labelled equivalent of the NASA 4K moon texture files?

Tags: the-moon, nasa, mapping

Does anyone know whether a labelled version of the [NASA 4k moon texture files](https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/4720) exists with the same projection?

I would like to be able to overlay and switch between the photographic versions, and a labelled version showing large crater names, mares, etc, so that it is easy to orient and see what I'm looking at.

Comment: I would expect you would be able to use the lat/lon coordinates to add the labels yourself: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_craters_on_the_Moon:_A%E2%80%93B

Comment: For that kind of projection, at that size, i think its a no. Would've been easily available by now, like all the other maps made available for such mapping